# Php store variable into html value field

Tags: php, html

I have a problem storing data from cookie into html value field. I am generating html with php.

Code:

```
 $cookieName = $_COOKIE["username"];
 $cookiePass = $_COOKIE["password"];

 if(isset($_COOKIE['username']) && isset($_COOKIE['password'])){
      echo "<input type='text' name='name' value='echo $cookieName'>";
      echo "<input type='password' name='pass' value= 'echo $cookiePass'>";
 }else{
      echo "<input type='text' name='name'>";
      echo "<input type='password' name='pass'>";
 }
```

Comment: Are those apostrophes correct?

Comment: So? Whats the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are wrongly outputting variables

Replace

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['username']) && isset($_COOKIE['password'])){
  echo "<input type='text' name='name' value='echo $cookieName'>";
  echo "<input type='password' name='pass' value= 'echo $cookiePass'>";
}
```

with

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['username']) && isset($_COOKIE['password'])){
  echo "<input type='text' name='name' value='{$cookieName}'>";
  echo "<input type='password' name='pass' value= '{$cookiePass}'>";
}
```

You are using `echo` within `echo`

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error. You should concatenate strings and variables instead of using echo twice without using semicolons between them. I would suggest to invert double quotes with quotes. Simply change to

```
echo '<input type="text" name="name" value="'. $cookieName.'">';
echo '<input type="password" name="pass" value= "'. $cookiePass.'">';
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
  echo "<input type='text' name='name' value='".$cookieName."'>";
  echo "<input type='password' name='pass' value= '".$cookiePass."'>";
```

instead of this -

```
  echo "<input type='text' name='name' value='echo $cookieName'>";
  echo "<input type='password' name='pass' value= 'echo $cookiePass'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
 echo "<input type='text' name='name' value='" . $cookieName . "'>";
```

You can't use the PHP function echo inside a String. So the solution is just to combine a string with your parameters.

A second way is to use {$var} like this:

```
echo "<input type='text' name='name' value='{$cookieName}'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$cookieName = $_COOKIE["username"];
$cookiePass = $_COOKIE["password"];

if(isset($_COOKIE['username']) && isset($_COOKIE['password'])){
    echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"name\" value=\"{$cookieName}\">";
    echo "<input type=\"password\" name=\"pass\" value=\"{$cookiePass\">";
} else{
    echo "<input type='text' name='name'>";
    echo "<input type='password' name='pass'>";
}
```